# How sort two arrays?

Tags: javascript

Please help me get my 2 arrays asc sorted and desc sorted. My solution has not worked

```
function solve(arr){
  var descArr = [];
  var ascArr = [];

  ascArr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  descArr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });

  console.log(descArr);
  console.log(ascArr);

};

solve([15,11,10,7,12])
```

Console.log displays similar sorted arrays.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8zmhzkkh/)

Comment: sort returns the sorted original array, so you have all references to the same array. you could take a copy with slice and sort then.

Comment: the sort method mutates the array you call it on, which is why they are the same. If you log the array before sorting for the second time, you'll see the results you wanted.

Comment: sort mutates the original array, you have to slice the original array to create a copy then do the mutation.

Comment: `
    var arr = [15,11,10,7,12];

    let sortA = arr.slice().sort((a,b) => a-b );
    let sortB = arr.slice().sort((a,b) => b-a );

    console.log(sortA);
    console.log(sortB); 
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get `descArr`, slice to get a shallow copy of the array, and sort. Slice `descArr` and Array#reverse to get `ascArr`.

You need to use Array#slice to get a shallow clone because both Array#sort, and Array#reverse are in place, which means that they mutate the original array.

```js
function solve(arr){
  var descArr = arr.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  
  var ascArr = descArr.slice().reverse();

  console.log(descArr);
  console.log(ascArr);

};

solve([15,11,10,7,12])
```